# How do I replace Mac Mini HDD with SSD with factory reset

Tags: mac, ssd, backup

I've Mac mini 2014 and planning on replacing its HDD with SSD but not sure how to perform backup and restoration like the way I want.

Basically, I want to have my Mac mini like it was shipped but with SSD, instead of HDD. i.e. it should only have macOS and preinstalled apps that come with new Mac.

I want to manually copy the data I want (as there's a lot of cherry picking), and then factory reset it and replace HDD with SSD.

Another thought I have is to install SSD and install a fresh copy of macOS but I doubt if I'll be getting those paid apps (keynote, iMovie etc.) with it that came preinstalled with Mac.

Comment: See [http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/246954/221318](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/246954/221318)